# How to make nested async requests firebase cloud functions (firestore)

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I have two tables (Users and Transactions). how to fetch for the transactions then get all the transactions user data using promises or async await. the simple aync await method isn't working it is not returing all the user data. only the first transaction user data.
``

```
export const getUserTransactions = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    if (!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'Unauthorized.');
    }
    const uid = data.uid;
    const transRef = firestore.collection("transactions");
    try {

        const bidDocs = await transRef.where('bid', '==', uid).orderBy('date').limit(3).get();
        const cidDocs = await transRef.where('cid', '==', uid).orderBy('date').limit(3).get();

        const [
            bidDocsQuerySnapshot,
            cidDocsQuerySnapshot
        ] = await Promise.all([bidDocs, cidDocs]);

        const bidDocsArray = bidDocsQuerySnapshot.docs;
        const cidDocsArray = cidDocsQuerySnapshot.docs;

        const transactionsArray = cidDocsArray.concat(bidDocsArray);

        //return transactionsArray;
        return Promise.all(transactionsArray.map(async doc => {
            console.log("cid"+doc.data()['cid']+"bid"+doc.data()['bid']);
            const tdata = doc.data();
            var id = "";
            
            if(doc.data()['bid'] == uid) {
                id = doc.data()['bid']
            }
            if (doc.data()['cid'] == uid) {
                id = doc.data()['cid'];
            }  
           
            return await firestore.collection("users").doc(id).get().then(async value=>{
               
                const udata = value.data();
                if (value.exists) {
                    //t.push({ tdata: tdata, udata: value.data() });
                    return { tdata: tdata, udata: udata };
                } else {
                    console.log('No matching documents.');
                    return;
                }
            });
           
        })).catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting documents', err);
        });
```

``

Comment: This is weird, everything seems ok. Might be an issue with lambda var capture. What happens if you print the id before the request? do you get 3 different ids?

Comment: Yes i get 3 differrent id's. The first two are the same user but the third is not (as expected).

Comment: lambda var capture?

Comment: As a result, i get three user data but it is the same user data.

Comment: Lambda var capture is when a value of a var outside a loop is being "captured" inside an inner function call, so you think you are using a looped value but you are only using the last one. Doesn't seem to be the case here though, so I really don't know.

Comment: It was my mistake. I was making sure to get only the current user data by doing this : `` if(doc.data()['bid'] == uid) {
                id = doc.data()['bid']
            }
            if (doc.data()['cid'] == uid) {
                id = doc.data()['cid'];
            }  ``I should have done this : ``
                id = doc.data()['cid'];
            `` instead.